# using solrj to add a new FieldType(java class object) to solr schema.xml -

Tags: java, solrj

I added a new fieldType to the solr `schema.xml` file like this:

```
fieldType class="myJavaClass" name="myClass"
```

But when I run solr it throws an error saying that it is undefined - where else does this new class have to be defined for solr to know about it?

Comment: The 'class' needs to be the fully qualified class name if it not one of the Solr standard ones.  What is the package of `myClass`?

Comment: the package is com.myJavaclass -& yes I updated the schema.xml file to reflect the package & generated a jar file for my class and added the jar to the solr.war - then when I started up solr I got the following exception thrown - "Plugin init failure for schema.xml Error loading class com.myJavaClass" - How do I get solr to recognize my java class so I can save that POJO using the solrj API?

Comment: The problem could have a number of causes - the class may not be found, it might not have extend the right class, it might not extend `org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType`, it might not have a public zero-argument constructor.  I suggest posting the full error message (if there is a stack trace all the better) and maybe some code from your field type class.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it I had no idea that I had to extend the FieldType class - so now when I try adding the bean to solr with my object that contains this new FieldType it seems to work but when I retrieve the bean - the new fieldType is null even tho I had data in it and the other values from the bean (not custom types are fine)

Comment: Cool - copied my comment into an answer so you resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(copied from comments as it was found to be a solution)

The problem could have a number of causes - the class may not be found, it might not have extend the right class, it might not extend org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType, it might not have a public zero-argument constructor. I suggest posting the full error message (if there is a stack trace all the better) and maybe some code from your field type class.